# Where is Hausdorff necessary in characterizing MaxSpec C(X), X compact Hausdorff?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am reviewing the attached proof that characterizes the maximal ideals of $C(X)$, the algebra of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space $X$ under the sup-norm and pointwise operations.

Define $M_x = \{f \in C(X) \vert f(x) = 0\}$. We show these are the maximal ideals: let $I \subsetneq C(X)$ be a proper ideal, and assume for the sake of contradiction that we can find for each $x \in X$ a function $f_x \in I$ that is not contained in $M_x$, i.e. $f_x(x) \neq 0$. Then by continuity, there exist open neighborhoods $U_x$ about each point $x$ such that $f_x(y) \neq 0$ for all $y \in U_x$. The collection of $(U_x)_{x\in X}$ form an open cover of $X$; by compactness, we can find a finite subcover $(U_{x_{n}})$. Set $f = f_{x_{1}}^2 + \dots + f_{x_{n}}^2$. We can show that $f > 0$ always -- it is a unit, hence it would generate all of $C(X)$, a contradiction.

Where in this proof did we need the Hausdorff assumption? I feel that I am missing something basic with the construction/characterization of the neighborhoods $U_x$, and just wanted to verify. Thank you so much.

Comment: "It would generate all of $C(X)$" is a contradiction to what, exactly? I've seen this result before but this particular proof has confused me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hausdorffness is not needed, but your proof has a gap.

You proved that each proper ideal $I$ is contained in some $M_x$. But this does not automatically mean that the $M_x$ are maximal ideals, i.e. that for each proper ideal $J$ and each $x \in X$ we have the implication
$$M_x \subset J \implies M_x = J .  \tag{1}$$

We know that $J \subset M_y$ for some $y \in X$. Hence we have $M_x \subset M_y$. If we can show that $M_x = M_y$, then also $M_x = J$.

So let us prove
$$M_x \subset M_y \implies M_x = M_y . \tag{2}$$

Let $M_x \subset M_y$. For $f \in M_y$ define $f_x : X \to \mathbb R, f_x(z) = f(z) - f(x)$. Then $f_x(x) = 0$, thus $f_x \in M_x$. Hence $f_x \in M_y$, i.e. $f_x(y) = f(y) - f(x) = 0$. Therefore $f(x) = f(y) = 0$ since $f \in M_y$. This means $f \in M_x$.

$(2)$ is true for any space $X$, neither compactness nor Hausdorffness is needed. Note, however, that in a non-Hausdorff $X$ we may have $M_x = M_y$ for distinct points $x, y$. As an example take any space $X$ with the trivial topology. Note that $X$ is compact, but non-Hausdorff if it has more than one point. $C(X)$ is the set of constant functions on $X$, thus $M_x = \{0\}$ for all $x \in X$.